# Castle Windsor Multiple Instances using Depends

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, castle-windsor

I need to have two instances of the same web service, the only difference is the url. I can't seem to find documentation on how to get it to differentiate based on the parameter name in the contructor. Is this possible? I'm trying to use .DependsOn, but I can't seem to get it to work when the Controller constructor instantiates.

Controller.cs constructor:

```
        private Service.IPlanService PlanServiceProd;
    private Service.IPlanService PlanServiceDev;

    public BackcheckController(Service.IPlanService PlanServiceProd, Service.IPlanService PlanServiceDev)
    {
        this.PlanServiceProd = PlanServiceProd;
        this.PlanServiceDev = PlanServiceDev;
    }
```

Global.asax.cs code:

```
       WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<Service.IPlanService>()
            .AsWcfClient()
            .Named("PlanServiceDev")
            .LifestyleTransient()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("PlanServiceDev", "PlanServiceDev"))
            .DependsOn((k, d) =>
                d["EndPoint"] = WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport) { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647 })
                                                  .At(new Uri(ClientAccountsUriDev, "plans"))
                                                  .AddExtensions(new WebHttpBehavior())
                                                  .AddExtensions(new ClientCredentialsEndPointBehaviour(ClientId, ClientSecret, ClientAccountsAudience, Issuer))
            )
            .Interceptors(new Castle.Core.InterceptorReference(typeof(MyCacheInterceptor))).Anywhere
            );

        WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<Service.IPlanService>()
            .AsWcfClient()
         .Named("PlanServiceProd")
         .LifestyleTransient()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("PlanServiceProd", "PlanServiceProd"))
         .DependsOn((k, d) =>
             d["EndPoint"] = WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport) { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647 })
                                               .At(new Uri(ClientAccountsUriProd, "plans"))
                                               .AddExtensions(new WebHttpBehavior())
                                               .AddExtensions(new ClientCredentialsEndPointBehaviour(ClientId, ClientSecret, ClientAccountsAudience, Issuer))
         )
         .Interceptors(new Castle.Core.InterceptorReference(typeof(MyCacheInterceptor))).Anywhere
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the hack I came up. Someone give me an award :)

```
            WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<Service.IPlanService>()
            .AsWcfClient()
            .LifestyleTransient()
            .DependsOn((k, d) =>
            {

                d["EndPoint"] = WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport) { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647 })
                                                  .At(new Uri(ServiceCount % 2 == 0 ? ClientAccountsUriImpact : ClientAccountsUriProd, "plans"))
                                                  .AddExtensions(new WebHttpBehavior())
                                                  .AddExtensions(new ClientCredentialsEndPointBehaviour(ClientId, ClientSecret, ClientAccountsAudience, Issuer));

                if (ServiceCount % 2 == 0)
                    ServiceCount = 1;
                else
                    ServiceCount = 0;

            } )
            .Interceptors(new Castle.Core.InterceptorReference(typeof(MyCacheInterceptor))).Anywhere
            );
```